# RuntimeException : when calling BillingClient function in in app purchase

Tags: android, runtime, in-app-billing, billing

```
private BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(activity)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build();
```

> I am integrating billing google api for purchase but when I call this method, I  get an error in place of activity.
> The error is:

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxxxx.xxxxx, PID: 9433
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxx.xxxx/com.xxxx.coins_history.activity.CoinsHistoryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2876)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:126)
    at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl.initialize(com.android.billingclient:billing@@4.0.0:1)
    at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl.<init>(com.android.billingclient:billing@@4.0.0:4)
    at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl.<init>(com.android.billingclient:billing@@4.0.0:9)
    at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient$Builder.build(com.android.billingclient:billing@@4.0.0:4)
    at com.jetmedianetwork.coins_history.activity.CoinsHistoryActivity.<init>(CoinsHistoryActivity.java:133)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Error handling uncaught exception
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.Utils.awaitEvenIfOnMainThread(Utils.java:122)
at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:231)
at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$1.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:153)
at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:54)
at com.facebook.internal.instrument.crashreport.CrashHandler.uncaughtException(CrashHandler.java:65)
at org.chromium.base.JavaExceptionReporter.uncaughtException(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-432418123:6)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1955)

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue here is that there is a Null Pointer in your code since the billing client has not bee instantiated.
Try modifying the code as follows

```
private BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient!!.newBuilder(activity)
        .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build();
```